# How to disable current and future month in Java.util.Calendar

Tags: java

How to disable current and future month in `java.util.Calendar`?

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    dateBox.setValue(calendar.getTime());
```

Here `dateBox` is `id` for the input type `DateBox` in UI.

Comment: What `DateBox` is that? `com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox`?

Comment: That is zkoss UI framework

Comment: <datebox id="dateBox"  width="150px" sclass="datebox-month-only"  format="MMM-yyyy"  visible="true"  constraint="no empty;no future"/>

Comment: this is showing error if i select future date, but i want hidden future months

Comment: How can you expect to restrict the Calendar class and disable future months? Isn’t it the DateBox class or other classes from that framework you need to work with?

Comment: dateBox is like html input type="date", so i want to disable or hide future months when open that Calendar.

Comment: @Gopi According to the [documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Reference/Input/Calendar), you can customize Calendar at the client by providing JavaScript code that overrides Renderer. See Calendar Day Renderer example.